# Is there a way to sync GSuite accounts to local WIndows Active Directory server?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, google-workspace

We are considering registering our organization's GSuite account information on our own Windows Server. There are some examples of synchronization from Active Directory to GSuite using Google Cloud Directory Sync or Directory Sync (beta), but I could not find the opposite as far as I searched.
My question is,

1. Is there any way to synchronize GSuite to Active Directory?

If it is impossible,

2. Is there a way to synchronize users from LDAP server to Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is no official solution to sync users in Google Workspace to users in Active Directory.

The closest official option is the opposite, you can sync users in Active Directory to Google Workspace using a tool called GCDS more information available in this Help Center article **https://support.google.com/a/topic/2679497**. If your environment is flexible you can do the opposite and only maintain your Active Directory environment schedule GCDS to sync every few days and effectively replicate your AD structure in Google Workspace. There are many settings that allow you to create just some users. GSPS (https://support.google.com/a/topic/2611858) syncs the password changes in AD to Google Workspace users, these are just one way sync tools. *As a Google Workspace consultant I recommend this approach.*

These are our options:

1. If you are looking for a solution to have your users sign in to their Windows computers with the same login information in Google Workspace consider using Google Credential Provider for Windows (GCPW - https://support.google.com/a/answer/9250996) your users will see a "Sign-in with Google" button and will be requested to enter their Google Workspace credentials.
2. You can create your own, with PowerShell you can make all the changes to your active directory environment, you can download a list of all your users from the Admin console as explained in this Help Center article https://support.google.com/a/answer/7348070. With a simple PowerShell script you can create all your users based on the data in the CSV file.
3. The previous option is not very flexible for large and changing organizations. You can repeat the same approach as option #2 with APIs, the Admin SDK Directory API  (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest) allows you to programmatically read the entire list of users, groups, organizational, among other things and recreate the same structure in AD.
4. Explore online for an already existing solution that does what I suggest in option #3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to provision users from Google Workspace Secure LDAP to a MS Active Directory using [LSC](https://lsc-project.org/index.html).

It seems to be compatible with all LDAP systems.

You can, of course, not sync passwords from Google to AD, as nothing is allowed to read passwords in Google. So if users are to use their Google credentials to log into something, you would have to set up some SSO login, so they are really logging in with the Google accounts, and not with the AD account. Or set up a password portal that pushes changes to both Google and your AD.

As suggested by Juan you could use GCPW for logging into the devices.